# Is there an equivalent to a worker service in .net-framework?

Tags: .net, .net-core, worker, .net-4.7.2

I need to write a long running service in `.net 4.7.2`. Actually in .net core I know about the worker services, but I am insecure if I can write those worker service in `.net 4.7.2` as well.

The use case is that I have a library (`.dll`) from an extern manufacturer written in `.net 4.7.2` to perform some actions on the delivered tablet from this manufacturer. I want my service to run on this tablet (windows 10) and poll some status information about this tablet (e.g. connection information) and send it to a `blazor webassembly` application using any technology like `gRPC`, `REST` etc...

So my question is how can I realize this using `.net 4.7.2`? I know about the worker services in `.net core` but it seems that Microsoft only supports those worker services for `.net core`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I would also like to know the answer.  I have existing services in Framework, and as part of out Core migration - which will take place in stages, I would like to get our existing service using Workers still in 4.8   If this can work, it makes our eventual migration easier.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Check out this playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uM9o8GsO_u4 Maybe this works for you

Comment: @MarcelMüller. The playlist of 9 year old videos?  About making old style windows services which is exactly what we have in our framework code?

Comment: @DanielWilliams And what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: As I understand it if you want to run Services in.net core without the framework so that your programs can run on Linux, then you have to use workers and not Services. But I could be completely wrong this is why I’m asking

Comment: @DanielWilliams Yes exactly basically you need dotnet core to run .net-based programs in linux. Therefore .net core offers the worker templates which can be configured to run in windows, linux and mac. To run a worker in linux you can use Systemd as described here:  https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-run-a-dotnet-core-console-app-as-a-service-using-systemd-on-linux